# How can we optimizing Java BigInteger operations?

Tags: java, performance, bigint

#### Problem

Reduce the number to 1 in a minimal number of steps, following the rules:

- If the number is even, divide it by 2.
- Otherwise, increment or decrement it by 1.

Limit: `s` can be up to 309 digits long.

#### Solution

```
public static int solution(String s) {
    BigInteger n = new BigInteger(s);
    BigInteger one = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger two = BigInteger.TWO;
    BigInteger four = new BigInteger("4");
    int count = 0;

    while (n.compareTo(one) == 1) {
        count++;

        if( n.and(one).intValue() == 0 )
            n = n.divide(two);
        else if ( n.intValue() == 3 || n.mod(four).intValue() == 1)
            n = n.subtract(one);
        else
            n = n.add(one);
    }

    return count;
}
```

**Is there a better way to do things binary-operations-wise for this problem?**

At the moment the choice I am making among these functions:

- use `n.byteValue()` to compare with the integer,
- or use function `n.equals()`.

What more can we improve?

---

Follow-up question posted [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/253626/folow-up-how-can-we-optimizing-java-biginteger-operations)

Comment: Limits and link to the problem please.

Comment: @superbrain Thanks. I have added limit in the problem description.

Comment: Why keep the source of the problem secret?

Comment: My bad @superbrain lol

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) as well as  [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ. Noted. Thanks.

Comment: With the last comments I'm not sure If I want to add this to the original question - How efficient is BigInteger when the input size is int or long? Should there be separate mechanism to handle these primitives? Or How efficient BigInteger handling them?

Answer (score 4):

Division of the big integers is a very expensive operation. Even a division by 2 is linear in terms of its length: all bits must be shifted. The overall complexity is \$O(n \log{n})\$.

A natural desire is to not do arithmetics at all, but simulate it. Convert the bigint to byte array, and inspect bits, *pretending* that you perform arithmetics. In broad strokes, run the loop (starting with `cursor = 0`) until the number is exhausted:

```
if bit(cursor) == 0
    // simulate division
    increment counter
    advance cursor
else
    peek next_bit
    if next_bit == 0
        // simulate subtraction
        increment counter by 2
        advance cursor by 2
    else
        // simulate addition
        while next_bit == 1
            increment counter
            advance cursor
            peek next_bit
        advance cursor
        set bit at cursor to 1
```

This touches each bit just once, driving the complexity down to \$O(n)\$. Care must be taken to correctly terminate the loop.

Comment: Can you explain how theirs is O(n log n)?

Comment: @KellyBundy As I said, each division is \$O(n)\$, and there are about \$O(\log{n})\$ of them.

Comment: Isn't each division O(log n)?

Comment: @KellyBundy Perhaps me being sloppy. To quote myself `in terms of its length` : \$n\$ in this analysis is not the bigint _value_, but its _length_; the number of bits.

Comment: This provides another dimension to solve the problem but looks a bit complicated, may be because I have not worked with Bits. But thank you @vnp for the perspective.

Comment: Hmm, the question makes n the value. Better don't use the same name for something else, especially not without saying so. Two different meanings for the same name are just confusing. You even seem to confuse yourself with it: you say there are O(log n) divisions, which is not true if n is the number of bits.

Comment: @vnp I still have not worked out on the logic you presented but would love to see some full fledged implementation examples if someone would like have some time, but I definitely am looking for do it myself as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## Divide by 2

As implemented, the even-test and divide by two operations is very inefficient.

`BigInteger` provides a [`getLowestSetBit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#getLowestSetBit()) function, which returns "the index of the rightmost (lowest-order) one bit"

So if `n.getLowestSetBit()` returns 12, you can evenly divide the value by 2 a total of twelve times, before the least significant bit is set.  Instead of actually doing the division by 2 that many times, the [`shiftRight(int n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#shiftRight(int)) function should be used:

```java
   while (n.compareTo(one) == 1) {

       int zeros = n.getLowestSetBit();
       if (zeros > 0) {
          n = n.shiftRight(zeros);
          count += zeros;
       } else {
          count++;
          if ( n.intValue() == 3 || n.mod(four).intValue() == 1)
             n = n.subtract(one);
          else
             n = n.add(one);
          }
       }
```

## Mod-4

Using `n.mod(four).intValue() == 1` to test whether the value should be incremented or decremented is also horribly inefficient.  Java must actually compute the modulo-4 remainder of the entire number; expecting it to optimize `n.mod(four).intValue() == 1` into the much faster `n.and(three).intValue() == 1` is expecting a lot from the optimizer.

But even computing `n.and(three)` is too much work!  We know `n` is larger than 1, and that bit #0 is set.  If bit #1 is set, then `n % 4 == 3`; if bit #1 is not set, then `n % 4 == 1`.  And `BigInteger` also provides the [`testBit(int n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#testBit(int)) function:

```java
          if ( n.intValue() == 3 || !n.testBit(1))
             n = n.subtract(one);
          else
             n = n.add(one);
          }
```

## Possible Bug

`n.intValue() == 3`

Since `n` can have over 300 digits, at any point in the process, the value of `n` can easily overflow an integer:

Consider the 33-bit value `0x100000003`.  The number is not 3, but the `intValue()` of the number is 3.

You probably want to explicitly test for value `BigInteger(3)`.  Since comparing the entire value may be slower than testing a single bit, you may want to reorder the test to check the bit first.

```java
          if ( !n.testBit(1) || n.equals(three) )
             n = n.subtract(one);
          else
             n = n.add(one);
          }
```

Comment: Maybe `n.bitCount() == 2` would be a fast "equals three" test?

Comment: @superbrain Hardly.  Counting number of bits different from the sign bit is not likely a fast operation.  Besides, it is wrong: `new BigInteger("5").bitCount() == 2`.

Comment: Oops, I meant `bitLength`.

Comment: @superbrain It may take many cycles to calculate `n.bitLength()` when you have a 300-digit value.  Equality comparison usually short-circuits at the first inequality, so is likely faster.  I'll admit, I haven't profiled -- I'm just guessing.  `n.bitLength() == 2` is true for `2`, `3`, `-3` and `-4`, so that test is **not** an obvious "equal to 3" test, despite the problem (probably) restricting the input numbers to positive values, and the previous even-odd test indicating we are on the odd path.

Comment: Surely it has the bit length already *stored* and wouldn't go and *calculate* it?

Comment: @superbrain The number of bytes (or possibly shorts, ints, or longs, depending on how it is implemented) would be stored.  But then the most-significant byte/short/int/long would need to be examined to determine how many bits it had.  That could be a lookup table if bytes were used, but anything larger would use too much memory.  Depending on the actual CPU architecture, there may be native instructions which would do much of the heavy lifting.  The monkey wrench is negative numbers, which would probably require an additional test at the start.

Comment: Ah, yes. At least [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/tip/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#l164), there is a field `bitLengthPlusOne` that [`bitLength`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/tip/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#l3679) looks up, but only if it's already initialized (and looks like that's only done by a previous `bitLength` call).

Comment: Negative numbers are already ruled out by the `while (n.compareTo(one) == 1)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117359/discussion-between-ajneufeld-and-superb-rain).

Answer (score 3):

You wrote:

> ```
>     while (n.compareTo(one) == 1) {
> ```

As [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#compareTo(java.math.BigInteger)) says:

> This method is provided in preference to individual methods for each of the six boolean comparison operators (`<`, `==`, `>`, `>=`, `!=`, `<=`). The suggested idiom for performing these comparisons is: `(x.compareTo(y) <op> 0)`, where `<op>` is one of the six comparison operators.

So that would be:

```
    while (n.compareTo(one) > 0) {
```

I also find that much easier to understand. You just need to read the three parts `n`, `one` and `>` and mentally move the `>` between the operands, i.e., `n > one`.